# What is the significance of the Activity used for runOnUiThread()?

Tags: android

I have an app with two activities .   One Activity is the "main" activity with a bunch of buttons on it, and the other Activity extends ListActivity and maintains a ListView and BaseAdapter.  There is also a worker thread that handles communication over WiFi with an external device and populates the datastore used by the adapter with information from the external device.

Only code running in the UI thread should ever touch the datastore used by an adapter, so in my worker thread I have code that's executed via a *runOnUiThread()* to populate the adapter.   *runOnUiThread()* is a method of the Activity class, so you need an Activity to call it.   I had intended to use the ListView activity to call it, but by mistake I used the main Activity instead.

And everything seems to work just fine. So my question is, what is the significance of what Activity is used to invoke runOnUiThread() from a worker thread?   The only parameter to that call is the action to be performed, so as long as that action is in scope and the Activity reference is not null, does it matter what Activity is used?

Comment: the context of the activity needs to be initialized. Note that you can also use a Handler created on the ui thread to post your runnables on the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

> The only parameter to that call is the action to be performed, so as long as that action is in scope and the Activity reference is not null, does it matter what Activity is used?

From the standpoint of `runOnUiThread()` itself, it does not matter what activity you use.

However, there should be exactly zero lines of code in your app where it is possible to access two `Activity` instances directly. The fact that apparently you have places in your app where you can access two (or more) `Activity` instances directly represents a serious code smell.